# How to make the text inside a specific cell of a table bold in PDF using Java?

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I'm creating a PDF document and inside of it i'm creating a table.

I want some cells to have bold text style.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before adding text to the cell, Create a new paragraph with the text you want to add.

```
Paragraph paragraph=new Paragraph("Test in the Cell");

paragraph.getFont().setStyle(Font.BOLD);

Cell c=new Cell(paragraph);

table.addCell(c);
```

For those Cells in which you need not want the bold just simply remove the line 
`paragraph.getFont().setStyle(Font.BOLD);`